# <select> tag in svelte doesn't work properly

Tags: html, svelte

```
<select>
    <option value="1">first</option>
    <option value="2">second</option>
    <option value="3">third</option>
    <option value="4">fourth</option>
</select>
```

I'm using this code to create a test dropdown selection in svelte, this code works in html but not svelte for some reason and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.
Clicking the dropdown does nothing.

Edit: As mentioned by people in the comment, apparently this code is correct and should work. I am using a Vite server on an embedded browser in vscode, if that helps clarify the situation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There must be something else going on in your code that is causing this. Maybe some css och js that do something to prevent the default behaviour.
If you take the above code and paste it on https://svelte.dev/repl/ it works without issues

Comment: Yes, but no. It was originally in more code, but to sus out where the problem is, I removed every other line of code except these 6 lines here, it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong, apparently the Vite extension in vscode is glitched and dropdown menus simply don't show up in the embedded browser. This code does work and is an extension problem.